# Sort ArrayList in Java - Multiple sorting criteria and adjustable priority

Tags: java, sorting

I have an ArrayList of custom objects. I want to sort this ArrayList by multiple fields and the priority in not known in compile time. I mean that I have to read the prioritization from a file. For Example :

Lets say that the custom object is :

```
class CustomObject{
   private int a;
   private int b;
   private int c;
 }
```

And I have a file that defines the priority of fields on sorting. For example :

a,b,c -> I have to sort on a then on b then on c

b,c,a -> Sort by b, c and a...

Can anyone suggest an approach on this?

Comment: On design level this looks like a prime example of the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You can implement your different priorities as different strategies and then select the correct one depending on your file. This would however lead to quite some extra code, on the other hand it would be very extendable if more sorting orders get added in the future.

Comment: https://medium.com/@lonell.liburd/chaining-comparators-and-sorting-in-java-498b8e1e34a8. You will need a MAP to tie your variable names to their respective comparators.

Comment: I researched both your options. I found it easier to use @PM77-1 's solution. I'll edit the post to include a complete solution. Thanks anyways